# Xpath, count node where attribute is null

Tags: xpath

I have a following XML.

```
<root>
    <a>
    </a>
    <a b="ar34" >
    </a>
    <a c="utr45">
    </a>
</root>
```

I want to do the count where attribute "b" is not present.
I am using the following but not getting the count

```
count(//*[string-length(a/@b) = 0]
```

How I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
count( //a[not(@b)] )
```

Here's a verbose explanation:

1. What do you want to count? `<a>` tags. So you start with `count( a )`
2. Where are these `<a>` tags? Everywhere in the document. So `count( //a )` it is then.
3. But you want to filter out some `<a>` tags, so you have to use a predicate (the bit in the square brackets): `count( //a[ ... ] )`
4. You want to only count those tags that have no `@b` attribute, so you put `not(@b)` in the predicate. (You can do this because an [attribute interpreted as a boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-ebv) is true if the attribute is present and false if it isn't.)